# SublimeText3 won't import matplotlib but terminal does

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, terminal, sublimetext3

So I'm trying to configure matplotlib for Python 3.4 in SublimeText3 (Mac OSX). I installed it (via pip and also via anaconda, because I was being dumb) and I am able to use it properly in terminal (so if I import matplotlib and make a simple graph it works perfectly).

When I do it instead in SublimeText3, I get an error saying that the matplotlib module cannot be found. I'm guessing (based on googling and some common sense) that it's a path issue but I'm kind of clueless as to how to fix this.

Do I need to change my path in the build or something? When I type "which python3.4" in terminal, I get a weird directory like "/Users/my_name/anaconda/bin/python3" although I recall when I initially configured my build the path had something to do with Library/Frameworks.

I don't know. Maybe my anaconda/matplotlib installation was bad.

I'd appreciate any help - sorry if it's a really dumb question.

Also, does SublimeText3 even generate graphs? I know I can do it in terminal but I was wondering if ST3 even supports GUI (I know I had issues with user inputs earlier...)

EDIT: The code I used. Works in terminal, not at all in SublimeText3

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.ylabel("Some numbers")
plt.show()
```

Comment: And your programming related question is what exactly? Where is the code that you have tried?

Comment: Sorry, I updated my original post with the code I used to generate a simple plot in terminal. Basically when I try it in SublimeText3 I'm not able to get anything because it keeps saying that matplotlib module can't be found and I'm not sure how to resolve that.

Comment: @redFIVE From [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic),  software questions are allowed if if they cover *"[...] software tools commonly used by programmers"*. Sublime Text, like vim, emacs, and Notepad++ (among others), is a programming editor, and there are tens of thousands of questions about them on this site that are perfectly on-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is occurring because you have multiple versions of Python on your computer. OS X ships with various versions of Python 2.x installed (I'm not sure if Py3 is also installed, I'm still on 10.8.5 where it is not). You have also installed the Anaconda distribution of 3.4, which is in your home directory, and likely the version from python.org as well, which is in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4`.

To solve your problem, first we need to figure out which version of Python you want to use. In Terminal, run these two commands:

```
which -a python3
which -a python3.4
```

to see where all (the `-a` switch) of the Python 3 executables in your `$PATH` live. You'll then need to pick the one you want to use in Sublime (you can use more than one if you want, I'll get to that later).

Now that we have the right path, we'll make a new [build system](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_processing/build_systems.html). Select **`Tools -> Build System -> New Build System…`**, delete the contents of the file that opens up, and add the following:

```js
{
    "cmd": ["/your/path/to/python3", "-u", "$file"],
    //       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

replacing `/your/path/to/python3` (underlined) with the actual path you chose above. Save the file as `Packages/User/Python3.sublime-build`, and a new `Python3` entry will appear in the **`Tools -> Build Systems`** menu. Click on it, and now you should be able to use `matplotlib` in your scripts.

---

As far as generating graphs, yes you will be able to plot images with `matplotlib`, `Pillow`, etc. They'll appear as a separate window when you run the script.

Comment: NEVERMIND IT WORKS! Thank you so much!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try typing `py -m pip install matplotlib` in commond prompt(cmd) It worked for me, hope it works for you as well.